# I don't understand why I have " cannot evaluate a function that has an argument without a value ('fetchurl') " when I try to build a package

Tags: nix

I try to build a nix package

a.nix :

```hs
{ lib
, stdenv
, fetchurl
, testVersion
, hello
}:
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "libfoo-1.2.3";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "http://example.org/libfoo-1.2.3.tar.bz2";
    sha256 = "0x2g1jqygyr5wiwg4ma1nd7w4ydpy82z9gkcv8vh2v8dn3y58v5m";
  };
}
```

then I execute this bash command

```bash
nix-build a.nix
```

> cannot evaluate a function that has an argument without a value ('fetchurl')

someone proposed me to write this command instead:

```bash
nix-build '<nixpkgs>' a.nix
```

It raised this error

```
    Please be informed that this pseudo-package is not the only part of
       Nixpkgs that fails to evaluate. You should not evaluate entire Nixpkgs
       without some special measures to handle failing packages, like those taken
       by Hydra.
```

I'm not that is the solution to the problem, lib was imported without problems.

Does somebody know where this problem comes from?

Comment: Those default arguments get filled in when you're invoked with `pkgs.callPackage`, but `nix-build` doesn't do that.

Comment: (Correction: The word "default" shouldn't have been present in the above comment; read it just as "Those arguments get filled in...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be invokable with `nix-build` and *also* with `pkgs.callPackage`, consider specifying default arguments:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { system = builtins.currentSystem; }
, lib ? pkgs.lib
, stdenv ? pkgs.stdenv
, fetchurl ? pkgs.fetchurl
, testVersion ? pkgs.testVersion
, hello ? pkgs.hello
}:
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "libfoo-1.2.3";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = "http://example.org/libfoo-1.2.3.tar.bz2";
    sha256 = "0x2g1jqygyr5wiwg4ma1nd7w4ydpy82z9gkcv8vh2v8dn3y58v5m";
  };
}
```

...but I don't generally advise that. Pick one calling convention or the other, don't do both. (In modern times, a flake is a great way to have a consistent structure for your code with inputs reliably pinned: if you had a flake.nix using `pkgs.callPackage` to invoke your derivation, that would let users invoke `nix build pathToYourFlake#nameOfThePackage` to build it -- `nix build .#` if it's the flake's default package and the current directory is a checkout of your flake).

Comment: The Nixpkgs architecture team is considering to stop calling package _functions_ `default.nix` in Nixpkgs, as they're not meant to be nix-build-able.

Comment: Duplicating the defaults is not advisable in nixpkgs, because the actual invocation by `callPackage` may pass different arguments, e.g. `callPackage ./some/pkg-fun.nix { hello = hello-rs; }`.

Comment: @RobertHensing, ...while we're in agreement that this isn't good practice, I think I'm missing something -- how does this defeat the `callPackage` usage you demonstrate in the comment above? I would expect an explicit argument to override the default.

Comment: The problem isn't so much that `callPackage` wouldn't work, but that the `nix-build pkg-fun.nix` invocation isn't representative of the attribute in Nixpkgs.

Comment: Right; I don't interpret the OP as building something for inclusion in nixpkgs -- if they were, there's a robust code review process that will iron things out -- but rather as trying to follow patterns they saw there.

Comment: In my experience, it becomes a problem in private projects too, but fair enough.

Comment: I think part of why I don't see it as a problem is that I expect the defaults to run... well, whatever's considered a default build. Testing the ability to run a default build is distinct from testing the ability to run a build with a non-default version of a dependency, and typically the non-default versions will have different entrypoints (`foo_jdk14` instead of just `foo`, f/e).

Comment: It depends on where you put the responsibility for selecting the default. If you put that responsibility in the package function, you might as well do `{ pkgs }:` as that has all you need. Otherwise, I'd put the defaults in the `callPackage` call.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./default.nix {}'`

Or if using buildPythonPackage:

`nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; with pkgs.python3Packages; callPackage ./default.nix {}'`

Comment: If there are any optional arguments (e.g. for Darwin and you are on Linux), add them inside the braces with dummy values, e.g. `nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; callPackage ./default.nix {AppKit=1; Foundation=1;}'`